# Prestashop - Product images not showing in category loop with friendly URLs

Tags: loops, prestashop

My product images don't show in categories after turning on friendly URLs. If I turn it off, they appear again.

I have tried :

- Re-generating pictures in the back-office
- Turning off cache

When I inspect the code with frienly URLs on, image links show in a weird format : https://www.website.fr/3689-home_default/.jpg

Prestashop 1.6

EDIT :

It appears the problem comes from the way I query products in my custom category TPL. I am querying products from subcategories manually (i am not displaying all products of the category at once) like this :

```
{foreach from=$subcategories item=subcategory}
    {if $subcategory.id_category == 64659}

        {assign var="subcategory_id" value=$subcategory.id_category}
        {assign var="subcategory_object" value=$subcategories_objects.$subcategory_id}
        {include file="./product-list.tpl" products=$subcategory_object->getProducts('1','1','100','price','asc')}

    {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

When I query products with the following line, images appear as normal :

```
{include file="./product-list.tpl" products=$products}
```

In the product-list.tpl, this is the line which gets the image :

```
src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any option like "Move Images" in Preferences -> Image in admin panel?

Comment: I don't see any option which looks like this, no. There is an option "Keep previous images" when i re-generate thumbnails, but I tried with and without it, it doesn't fix.

Comment: Are you able to see images in admin panel in product listing?

Comment: Yes, they show up perfectly.

Comment: What is url of that images?

Comment: For the same product : 
Back-office : "../img/tmp/product_mini_2274_1.jpg?time=1536329452" 
|||  Front-office : "https://www.website.fr/3812-home_default/.jpg"

Comment: Are you using default theme?

Comment: No, this is a custom theme. I am going to try with the default one.

Comment: I found using default theme more precisions about the problem, I am updating the original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179661/discussion-between-malcom-and-divyesh-prajapati).

Answer (score 0):

By default you will get array of subcategories only in `$subcategories` variable; so getting products of that sub category will never work `$subcategory_object->getProducts('1','1','100','price','asc')` until and unless you do have sub category object.

First you need to get sub category object and for that you need to override default function `getSubCategories` from `classes/Category.php` file by making **override** of Category class.

Follow below mentioned steps(1-2) to create override class and modify code in template mentioned in step(3)

1) Make file `Category.php` on path `override\classes` and add below code in it.
this will override default function to get category.

```
<?php
/**
 * @override classes/Category.php
 * 
 */
class Category extends CategoryCore
{
    /**
     * @override
     * Return current category childs
     *
     * @param int $id_lang Language ID
     * @param bool $active return only active categories
     * @return array Categories
     */
    public function getSubCategories($id_lang, $active = true)
    {
        $result = parent::getSubCategories($id_lang, $active);
        foreach ($result as &$row) {
            // Preapre object of sub category here
            $row['object'] = new Category($row['id_category'], $id_lang);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

2) Delete file `class_index.php` from `cache` folder.

Your override function is ready now.

3) Add below code to your template to show products

```
{foreach from=$subcategories item=subcategory}
    {if $subcategory.id_category == 64659}
        {include file="./product-list.tpl" products=$subcategory.object->getProducts('1','1','100','price','asc')}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Hope this will work for you.